# How to store a Unix alias?

Tags: unix, shell

I know I can create an alias for untar like this

```
alias untar=’tar -xvzf’
```

How do I make this persist from session to session, because it seems it is lost when I reconnect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated, `~/.bashrc` is where you want to place them. You may like this little function I use to create aliases (place it in your `~/.bashrc` file).

```
function mkalias ()
{
        if [[ $1 && $2 ]]
        then
        echo -e "alias $1=\"$2\"" >> ~/.bashrc
        alias $1="$2"
        fi
}
```

The basic syntax is: `mkalias <name> "<command>"`

an example would be: `mkalias trsh "mv --target-directory=$HOME/.Trash"`

the command is always placed in quotes in case there are spaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code snippet. I'm new to bash will try to get this work :)

Comment: This function has a small bug. You forgot to quote `$2` in `alias $1=$2`. See: http://superuser.com/questions/114690/linux-bash-why-does-it-says-xvzf-not-found

Answer (score 6):

You usually write the alias in `$HOME/.bashrc` (if you are using the bash shell).

Otherwise take a look at [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell#Configuration_files_for_shells) to know which configuration file your shell will read.

In order to know which shell you are using look at the `SHELL` environment variable with:

```
$ echo $SHELL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to your .profile or .bashrc. There are usually some other aliases there, so follow those examples and you should be just fine.