# why my function in bashrc is not recognized on command line?

Tags: linux

I have added mkalias in my .bashrc file as I learnt here

[How to store a Unix alias?](https://superuser.com/questions/114546/how-to-store-a-unix-alias)

```
function mkalias ()
{
        if [[ $1 && $2 ]]
        then
        echo -e "alias $1=\"$2\"" >> ~/.bashrc
        alias $1=$2
        fi
}
```

but when I type mkalias on command line it says command not found. Why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type:

```
$ source .bashrc
```

in order to read the content of the modified `.bashrc` file.

You can also exit and reopen the terminal to make the changes take effect.

Every time you modify `.bashrc` you have to source it or restart the terminal to see the effects of the modifications.