# Linux Bash alias: Why does it says -xvzf not found 

Tags: linux, bash, alias

I have used mkalias suggested here
[How to store a Unix alias?](https://superuser.com/questions/114546/how-to-store-a-unix-alias)

by typing

```
mkalias untar "tar -xvzf"
```

but it says

> -xvzf not found

Why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function posted in that other answer has a bug. The line

```
alias $1=$2
```

should read

```
alias $1="$2"
```

The answerer remembered to quote the second argument in the line that inserts the alias into your bashrc, but forgot to quote it when activating the alias for the current session.